# AMPPS not displaying errors?

Tags: php

I looked PHP.ini files but error mode is on there?

But when there is error in my code I cannot see php showing error??

I use local host called AMPPS.

And whenever there is error i see blank page like if i use:

```
require('something.php');
```

There is a blank page instead of showing fatal error or warnings.

I use [CodeCanyon](http://codecanyon.net) script. Can script change the error showing mode?

How can I display all there error even if it is small on as I am on development mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can script change the error showing mode?

Yes, it can. For starters you can set this in your PHP file—before code like `require('something.php');`—to force errors to show:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

But that said, if errors are not displayed at all, check your Apache logs in your setup. Unclear on where in AMPPS the logs would be stored—or what your host system running AMPPS is—but there should be a log in there somewhere.

Comment: yes figured out there is that lhat line of code in script

Comment: THanks man you saved me alot...i found many error logs about php errors..thanks a million